# Expressing Euler Rotation in Degrees | Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, units

While learning Geometry Nodes and constructing a functional clock face, I ran into an issue.

My animation should be a minute long - 1800 frames at 30FPS.

In the first part of my graph, I am multiplying the current frame number (*#frame*) by the value a second pin should move with each frame - 360deg/1800 expressed in radians as (*tau/1800*).

I then convert this value to degrees with the *To Degrees* Math Node. Same functionality could be achieved without conversion, working with Radians only. But seeing as the Conversion node exists, I had hoped to use it.

[image: Left part of the graph network, Two value nodes (frame and 0.2deg), Multiplied and converted To Degrees]

Later, this value is plugged into the Y slot of a *Combine XYZ* node. My goal was to create a Vector which could then be input into the Rotation of a *Transform Geometry* node.

It is here, where I suspect the problem arises.

[image: Right part of the graph network, a Combine XYZ node plugged into the Rotation Input of a Transform Geometry node]

At frame 450, the Second_pin object should be rotated by 90° along the Y-axis. The output of a *Combine XYZ* node is a *(0,90,0) Vector*.

This doesn't happen. Instead, the output looks like this:

[image: Clock face at frame 450, the Second_pin object should be at exactly 90 degrees]

My guess is that the *Transform Geometry* node uses a different data type to express rotation internally and my Vector gets converted wrongly. Is there a way to fix this?

Is it desirable to use degrees internally like this?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: welcome. It's seems that the conversion is already done by the Transform Geometry so the Convert to Degree repeat the transformation. Delete it, it should work find. If I’m not mistaking something…

Comment: Yeah, it's just confusing interface.  The rotation field expects degrees if you type numbers into it.  But if you plug a noodle it, it expects radians.

Answer (score 2):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

Angles in *degree* are supported only as direct inputs by the *Transform Geometry* node, if *degree* is the angle unit chosen by the user. As soon as the *Rotation* socket is connected, it is expecting radians. In the following GN graph, whatever the switches, the result is the same.

[image: GN Graph]

Resources: [image]